# Access registered service from Program.cs in ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-6.0

In my Program.cs file I'm registering two repositories on `builder.Services` that will be used via dependency injection.  However, I now have a case where I need to call one to configure the other. So essentially I need to do this:

```cs
builder.Services.AddFirstService();

var tempProvider = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider();
var injected = tempProvider.GetRequiredService<IFirstService>();
var password = await injected.GetPasswordAsync();

builder.Services.AddSecondService(password);
```

That of course gives a warning about creating duplicate services. Is there a way to properly inject the first service so that I can then use it in another call?

The second service isn't something that can be modified to know about the first service.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20408625/injecting-a-service-into-another-service).

Comment: @QingGuo That's explicitly what I said I can't do.  Assume that both services are third party items that I don't control the source code to.

Comment: @Steven Again, I agree, but I don't own the code base.  I can't change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The password is runtime data. This means you should design that component as such that it [doesn't require runtime data during creation](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/p/runtime-data/) but instead allow to fetch the password lazily after it was created.

In case the component can't be changed—for instance because it comes from a third-party library—it's best to hide its use behind an abstraction. This also makes sure you adhere to the Dependency Inversion Principle, which states that:

> high level modules should own the abstractions they depend on.

For instance, inside your application layer, you can create an abstraction such as the following:

```cs
public interface IApplicationTailoredAbstraction
{
    Task DoSomething();
}
```

Application code that originally depended on the third-party component can now start to take a dependency on `IApplicationTailoredAbstraction` instead.

Inside your application's [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/), you can now create an Apapter that adapts from `IApplicationTailoredAbstraction` to the third-party component:

```cs
public class AppTailoredToThirdPartyComponentAdapter
    : IApplicationTailoredAbstraction
{
    public AppTailoredToThirdPartyComponentAdapter(IFirstService firstService) ...

    // Optionally cache the password (depending on your needs)
    private string password;

    public async Task DoSomething()
    {
        if (password is null)
        {
            password = await firstService.GetPasswordAsync();
        }

        // Create the third-party library component
        var service = new SecondService(password);

        // Invoke its method(s)
        await service.Run();
    }
}
```

The registration of your components can now be done as follows:

```cs
builder.Services.AddFirstService();

builder.AddSingleton<IApplicationTailoredAbstraction,
    AppTailoredToThirdPartyComponentAdapter>();
```